# sum of same key from json object using $.each loop jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
"data": [{
  "Nic": {
    "2017-09":6473,
    "2017-10":66,
    "2017-11-01":69571
  },
  "Nancy": {
    "2017-09":185,
    "2017-10":194,
    "2017-11":2031
  }
}]
```

I want to get

```
series: [{
  dateValue: '2017-09',
  data: [6473, 185]
}, {
  dateValue: '2017-10',
  data: [66, 194]
}, {
  dateValue: '2017-11',
  data: [69571, 2031]
}]
```

Comment: The operaition that i performed

var arrPlaylist = [], arrData = [];
$.each(response['data'], function(name, Data) {
    arrPlaylist.push(name);
    var data = []; var dateArr = [];
    $.each(Data, function(index, Value) {
        
        if ($.inArray(index, dateArr) === -1){
            dateArr.push(index);
        }
        data.push(Value);
    }); 

    arrData.push({
        'name': dateArr,
        'data': data
    });
});

Comment: Put the content that you have put in comment as the code in your quetion, so that it will help people understand the question in better manner

Comment: "Nic" has "2017-11-01". why does it has yyyy-mm-dd format while others has yyyy-mm formt

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var data = [{
  "Nic": {
    "2017-09":6473,
    "2017-10":66,
    "2017-11":69571
  },
  "Nancy": {
    "2017-09":185,
    "2017-10":194,
    "2017-11":2031
  }
}];

var series = [];

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
var dates = Object.keys(data[0][keys[0]]);

$.each(dates, function(i){
  var temp = {};
  temp["dateValue"] = dates[i];
  temp["data"] = [];
  $.each(keys, function(j){
    temp["data"].push(data[0][keys[j]][dates[i]]);
  });
  series.push(temp);
});

console.log(series);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

I used [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/), i would recommend you to use it. However you can easily convert this to jQuery.

```js
var data = [{
  "Nic": {
    "2017-09":6473,
    "2017-10":66,
    "2017-11":69571
  },
  "Nancy": {
    "2017-09":185,
    "2017-10":194,
    "2017-11":2031
  }
}];
var d = data[0];
var k = Object.keys(d);
var v = [];
_.forEach(k, function(ky){v.push(d[ky])});
var f = [];
_.forEach(v, function(vl){
 var kys = Object.keys(vl);
 _.forEach(kys, function(ky){
  var val =_.findWhere(f, {dateValue: ky});
        if(!val){
           val = {dateValue: ky, data: []};
           f.push(val);
        }
        val.data.push(vl[ky]);
 });
});
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(f);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="val">

</div>
```